# How is the personal certificate generated in chrome?

Tags: ssl

I found this reading some documentation on Oracle's site.

> Blockquote
>   Low-security browser certificates are easy to acquire and can be done
>   from within the Web browser, usually by selecting the Security menu
>   item in Options or Preferences. Go to the Personal Certificates item
>   and ask to obtain a new digital certificate. You will be asked for
>   some information about yourself.

I don't see any such thing in chrome... which browser are they talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get certificate to .crt file:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect yourdomain:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > yourdomain.crt
```

and add it to system certificates(depends on system)
on MAC you need to select "always trust" after adding on certificate system manager.